# Send request GROUP by

Tags: mysql

How to group the data so that the sorting is respected?

```
SELECT tt.id_img, 
   tt.number_public, 
   tt.time_post, 
   tt.id_public 
FROM (SELECT 
        `number_public`, 
        `id_img`, 
        `time_post`, 
        birthday_publics.id_public

        FROM  birthday_time_post LEFT JOIN birthday_publics 
        ON  birthday_publics.id = birthday_time_post.number_public 
        WHERE birthday_time_post.time_post IN(
                                              SELECT MIN(time_post) 
                                              FROM   birthday_time_post 
                                              GROUP  BY number_public
                                           ) 
        ORDER  BY time_post
    ) tt
```

Sort by column  time_post

Photo request
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRd7T.png)

Comment: Use English please!

Comment: Group by should no rely on the ordering of the underlying data. You probably want records with max or min time_post values.

Comment: Yes, I need records with the minimum time_post

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```
  SELECT 
          b.`number_public`, 
          b.`id_img`, 
          b.`time_post`, 
          birthday_publics.id_public

  FROM  birthday_time_post b
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MIN(time_post) min_time
      FROM   birthday_time_post 
      GROUP  BY number_public
  ) t on t.min_time = b.time_post 
  LEFT JOIN birthday_publics  ON  birthday_publics.id =b.number_public 

  order by b.time_post
```